# Why my GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived is not called when app is not running?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I need to create and show some custom push notifications (need to pass some data and open some certain Activity when clicked) in my application. I did everything like described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config).

When application is running everything works as expected. But when it's in background my service is not started and I get a push notification which takes me to app's splash screen.

I researched a lot but didn't find explanation of this behavior.
Can anybody please tell me why is my service ignored when application is in background?

This is in my manifest file:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.locdel.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.locdel.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

......................

<application
    android:name=".LocdelApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.locdel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.locdel.gcm.LocdelGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.locdel.gcm.LocdelIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

.......................
```

I even tried to extend my own wakeful broadcast receiver and start service explicitly. This is custom receiver's onReceive method, which is actually called, but service was not started again:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LocdelGcmListenerService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
    serviceIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you show how you have declared the service in your manifest.xml and the code of the service as well ?

Comment: Updated my question. Code in service actually doesnt matter. I've override the onMessageReceived method and put some logs in there. So I know that service is not started at all

Comment: What are the permissions you mentioned into manifest file?

Comment: Updated again, guys, I said I did everything like described.

Comment: Have you checked onReceive is called with a simple log instruction ? When you are in background ?

Comment: Have you got any solution for your problem? If yes please help me because I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link given below:

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/push-notification-using-gcm-in-android.html

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It didn't. As I mentioned everything works fine when app is running.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check whether activity is running or not when a messsage received like this way

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.myapp")){

        updateMyActivity(message);  //send broadcast to notify app



        //Activity Running
//            Send a broadcast with the intent-filter which you register in your activity
//            where you want to have the updates
        }
        else{
            //Activity Not Running
            //Generate Notification
            sendNotification(message);
        }
```

Comment: Where? The problem is the message is NOT received.

Comment: @shift66 I am a bit unclear is onReceived called when the application is in background or not ?

Comment: Yes, onReceive of BroadcastReceiver is called and I even start manually the service there, it's not started for some reason

Answer (score 0):

try to call notification in this way from onReceive

```
 private void sendNotification(String message) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,FullMapActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.my_notif_color);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            /*PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 *//* Request code *//*, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);*/

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {



                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.headerlogo)
                        .setContentTitle("hey..! your booking is confirmed")
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
            }
            else
            {

                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.headerlogo)
                        .setContentTitle("hey..! your booking is confirmed")
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
    //                    .setColor(color)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63

In the above link it is clearly mentioned that if "notification" payload is present, then android will trigger the notification. Try removing the "notification" payload and send just the "data" payload, your [onMessageReceived](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive) should be called.

Comment: how to handle iOS? it seems iOS only handle "notification" payload

Comment: Yes. You cannot control the notification in IOS. It's the server that initiated the notification and the notification just gets displayed in the phone. Server will have to specify the target view and other information. App can for sure not handle it when it is killed. It may handle it when it is in background mode (not sure about it though). That's the reason why Whatsapp sends a different notification for each message received. While in Android it will accumulate them and show them as one. Hope this helps